# DetailsView Fields not Changing to Textboxes in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I created a DetailsView programmatically and I added a button to fire commands for the add, edit and delete.

Here's the event handler for the commands:

```
switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "Add":
                    dvSpotlightListDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
                    break;
                case "Edit":
                    dvSpotlightListDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
```

The add/insert commands changes the fields on the DetailsView to textboxes. But when selecting the edit command nothing happens.

I'm not so familiar with the process of the DetailsView when made through code-behind so I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Creating a DetailsView programmatically??  You're asking for lots of problems!  First off, every single control with an event needs to be re-created on every post-back, or the events won't fire...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that... Sadly I'm not sure what else to use as an alternative to DetailsView. :|

Comment: I have a similar issue but I don't create the details view dynamically. I have a custom busienss and data layer that performs all the sql stuff. I have a similar function like the one above but when I handle the OnItemCommand Event the details view does not display the edit fields. It continues to display the read only fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1249276.aspx/1
http://www.shotdev.com/aspnet/aspnet-vbnet-detailsview/aspnet-vbnet-detailsview-edit-update/